# VBA code to protect all worksheets contingent on response

Tags: vba, excel

To delete a name and correlating data in the same row on each sheet of my workbook, users need to highlight a name and click a button on the first worksheet. A confirmation window then pops up asking if they are sure. If they click NO, everything remains protected and works fine.  If they click YES, all worksheets are unprotected, and a second confirmation window appears - If YES is clicked the second time, the data is deleted from each worksheet and everything is protected after deletion. HOWEVER, if NO is clicked the second time, I can't get my code to then protect everything prior to exiting the sub.

Any help is appreciated, as well as suggestions for resources to help be become more proficient on my own. :)

Here is the code:

```
Sub DeleteRow()
'this macro deletes the row for a selected patient from worksheet of selected month and all months after that

    'variables
    Dim PatientName As String, PatientRow As Long, w As Long
    Dim pRow As Long, lRow As Long, LookUpRng As Range, answer As Long
    Dim rArray() As Variant, sArray As Variant
    ReDim rArray(0)
    ReDim sArray(0)


With ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Unprotect "arafluid"
    PatientName = .Range("d" & ActiveCell.Row)
    PatientRow = ActiveCell.Row
    .Rows(PatientRow).Interior.ColorIndex = 4



    'check that user want has selected correct patient
    answer = MsgBox("Do you want to permanently remove patient " & vbCr & vbCr & _
        PatientName & " from ALL months in this workbook?", vbYesNo, "Confirmation")
            .Rows(PatientRow).Interior.ColorIndex = -4142
                If answer = vbNo Then ActiveSheet.Protect "arafluid"
                If answer <> vbYes Then Exit Sub


    'check that it is safe to delete rows in future sheets
    For w = Worksheets.Count To ActiveSheet.Index Step -1

        With Sheets(w)
        Sheets(w).Unprotect "arafluid"
            pRow = 0
            lRow = .Range("d10").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 9
            Set LookUpRng = .Range("d10" & ":d" & lRow)

            On Error Resume Next
                pRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(PatientName, LookUpRng, 0) + 9
                    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                        Trail = Trail & vbCr & "  " & .Name & " Not Found!"
                    Else
                        Trail = Trail & vbCr & "  " & .Name & " ok"
                        ' add value on the end of the arrays
                        ReDim Preserve rArray(UBound(rArray) + 1) As Variant
                        ReDim Preserve sArray(UBound(sArray) + 1) As Variant
                        rArray(UBound(rArray)) = pRow
                        sArray(UBound(sArray)) = w
                    End If
            On Error GoTo 0
                End With
    Next w
        'check that user still wants to delete
        answer = MsgBox("Once deleted, the information cannot be recovered. Click YES to permanently remove: " & vbCr & vbCr & _
               PatientName & vbCr, vbYesNo, "Are you sure?")
                        If answer <> vbYes Then Exit Sub
                        If answer <> vbNo Then
                        For a = Worksheets.Count To ActiveSheet.Index Step -1
                        Sheets(a).Protect "arafluid"
                        Next a
                        End If



    'delete rows for selected patient

    For d = 1 To UBound(sArray)
        Sheets(sArray(d)).Rows(rArray(d)).EntireRow.Delete
    Next d

End With

'loop through all sheets in the workbook.
For w = 1 To Sheets.Count
Sheets(w).Protect "arafluid"
Next w


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are exiting the Sub if the user said "no". Change these lines after the second MessageBox:

```
answer = MsgBox("Once deleted, the information cannot be recovered. Click YES to permanently remove: " & vbCr & vbCr & _
     PatientName & vbCr, vbYesNo, "Are you sure?")

If answer = vbNo Then    'This will test if user said "No" and will protect the sheets
    For a = Worksheets.Count To ActiveSheet.Index Step -1
    Sheets(a).Protect "arafluid"
    Next a
    Exit Sub
End If
```

As a note, after the first `MsgBox` you have the same situation with two `If` statements for the same thing, you could simplify them as:

```
            If answer = vbNo Then 
                ActiveSheet.Protect "arafluid"
                Exit Sub
            End If
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks so much!